# k8s: get events from specific node

Tags: kubernetes

I want to know how to get events which are running on a specific node.

In my case my k8s cluster is made up of 3 worker nodes (node1,node2,node3). I want to get a list of all the events that are getting executed on node2.

I know i can get namespace specific events by:
kubectl get event --namespace default

Is there a way/option to get something like:
kubectl get event --nodename node2

Comment: This dosn't work
kubectl get events --field-selector involvedObject.kind=Node,involvedObject.name=node

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
kubectl get events --all-namespaces  | grep -i node01
```

this command gives me pod scheduled events too

```
master $ kubectl get events --all-namespaces  | grep -i node01
default       46s         Normal    Scheduled                 pod/nginx- 
dashrath                             Successfully assigned default/nginx- 
dashrath to node01
default       10m         Normal    Scheduled                 pod/nginx                                      
Successfully assigned default/nginx to node01
default       11m         Normal    NodeHasSufficientMemory   node/node01                                    
Node node01 status is now: NodeHasSufficientMemory
```

Comment: event by default dont include nodenames and hence grep wont work.

Comment: I tried the following but it also didnt work:
[root@node2 ~]# kubectl get events --all-namespaces --field-selector spec.nodeName=node2
Error from server (BadRequest): Unable to find "/v1, Resource=events" that match label selector "", field selector "spec.nodeName=node2": field label not supported: spec.nodeName

Comment: @user1999424 on my cluster both commands are working

Comment: [root@kubdvm01 ~]# kubectl get events --all-namespaces | wc -l
155
[root@kubdvm01 ~]# kubectl get events --all-namespaces | grep -E -i 'node1.eur.ad.sag|node2.eur.ad.sag|node3.eur.ad.sag'
default         42m         Warning   CheckLimitsForResolvConf   node/vmkubdvn02.eur.ad.sag                                          Resolv.conf file '/etc/resolv.conf' contains search line consisting of more than 3 domains!

Comment: out of 155 events only 1 is displayed with grep

Answer (score 0):

This is what works

```
$ kubectl get events --all-namespaces -o wide | grep -i node01
```