# Golang/Kubernetes: How to get/describe Node events

Tags: go, openshift, kubernetes-go-client

I am trying to get a specific node events through Golang Kubernetes client.

something similar to events we get when I run `kubectl describe node <node-name>` the lower end part of events.

I am able to get pod events but not sure how to do the same for a node.

```
events, _ := coreClient.CoreV1().Events("spark").List(context.TODO(), metav1.ListOptions{FieldSelector: "involvedObject.name=spark-t2f59", TypeMeta: metav1.TypeMeta{Kind: "Pod"}})
```

**Update:**

I am not sure if using .Get can help with that? I am not sure what string is expected in below syntax ?

```
events, err := coreClient.CoreV1().Events(namespace).Get(context.TODO(), STRING-HERE, metav1.GetOptions{})
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [k8s: get events from specific node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63090848/k8s-get-events-from-specific-node)

Comment: @HectorMartinezRodriguez - No as this answer is for kubectl not golang.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to get the Node's events just as you did for a Pod, just by replacing the "Kind" option in your query:

```
    namespace := "my-namespace"
    nodeName := "my-node-71544c18-8wn3"

    events, err := clientset.CoreV1().Events(namespace).List(context.TODO(), metav1.ListOptions{
        TypeMeta: metav1.TypeMeta{
            Kind: "Node",
        },
        FieldSelector: "involvedObject.name=" + nodeName,
    })
```

Comment: Thanks @Guillaume for your quick reply, I tried that and I am getting empty Items "Events" although when i do kubectl describe the node i see the events.

Comment: It worked :) Just added namespace as "default" and it worked"